# Can't find Domain Controller

Tags: active-directory

Started out Trying to apply Cumulative Update CU14 to Exchange 2013, failed due to error:

```
> Error: Setup can't use the domain controller 'Default-First-Site-Name'
> because it belongs to Active Directory site ''. Setup must use a
> domain controller in the same site as this computer
> (xxxxx.xxxxxxxx.com). For more information, visit:
> http://technet.microsoft.com/library(EXCHG.150)/ms.exch.setupreadiness.DomainControllerIsOutOfSite.aspx
```

So I looked at the link, and it says:

```
> The schema master is not running Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1 or
> later_DomainControllerIsOutOfSite
```

but both my Domain Controllers are running Win Server 2016. 
The error message says:

```
> *because it belongs to Active Directory site ''*,
```

with a blank. What's that about?

So I started checking out my DCs. I ran DCDiag on my Primary DC (Asgard), and it reported an error.

```
> D:\ExchangeCU14>dcdiag
> 
> Directory Server Diagnosis
> 
> Performing initial setup:    Trying to find home server...    Home
> Server = Asgard    * Identified AD Forest.    Done gathering initial
> info.
> 
> Doing initial required tests
> 
>    Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\ASGARD
>       Starting test: Connectivity
>          ......................... ASGARD passed test Connectivity
> 
> Doing primary tests
> 
>    Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\ASGARD
>       Starting test: Advertising
>          Warning: **DsGetDcName returned information for** **\\Elsinore.areteind.com, when we were trying to reach**
>          **ASGARD.**
>          **SERVER IS NOT RESPONDING or IS NOT CONSIDERED SUITABLE.**
>          **......................... ASGARD failed test Advertising**
```

So I checked, and Asgard is set as the PDC, and it is a Schema Master, and has all five FSMO roles assigned to it. Elsinore is the backup or secondary DC, and is also a schema master. Both have DNS running on them and Replication appears to be running in both directions.

Why is `DsGetDcName` ***.... returning information for Elsinore ....***  (the backup)  when it is ***....trying to reach Asgard ...***  (the PDC) ?

When I checked, the Active Directory SItes and Services "Cannot Locate Primary Domain Controller"

I checked Dns and they are both Asgard and Elsinore are properly registered with the correct IPs. 
On a hunch, I ping them both, and the results were interesting.
(Asgard IP4 is set to 192.168.87.2 and Elsinore is 192.168.87.3)

```
> D:\ExchangeCU14>ping 192.168.87.2  
> Pinging 192.168.87.2 with 32 bytes of data:    
> Reply from 192.168.87.2: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128 Reply from
> 192.168.87.2: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128


> D:\ExchangeCU14>ping Asgard   
> Pinging Asgard.areteind.com
> [fe80::f410:6f29:783e:9b6d%9] with 32 bytes of data:   
> Reply from fe80::f410:6f29:783e:9b6d%9: time<1ms Reply from
> fe80::f410:6f29:783e:9b6d%9: time<1ms
```

Why is ping by FQDN use the IPv6 address and not the IPpv4 address?

This is IpConfig /all from Asgard: ( there are two NICs in the machine and they are on a TEAMed connection named TeamAsgard:

```
> D:\ExchangeCU14>ipconfig /all
> 
> Windows IP Configuration
> 
>    Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Asgard    Primary Dns Suffix  .
> . . . . . . : areteind.com    Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . :
> Hybrid    IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No    WINS Proxy
> Enabled. . . . . . . . : No    DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . :
> areteind.com
> 
> Ethernet adapter TeamAsgard:
> 
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :      
>    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Network Adapter Multiplexor Driver    
>    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-1F-29-C9-1E-52      
>    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No       
>    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes     
>    Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f410:6f29:783e:9b6d%9(Preferred)
>    IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.87.2(Preferred)      
>    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0      
>    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.87.1      
>    DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 201334569    
>    DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1E-2D-CF-83-00-1F-29-C9-1E-52    
>    DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.87.2     
_______________________192.168.87.3        
>    NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled    
> 
>Tunnel adapter isatap.{FDE8723C-2280-4314-8A87-E79DE2C1A433}:
> 
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected   
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    
>    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2    
>    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0      
>    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No      
>    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

If I run NLTEst /DCName, I get:

```
> D:\ExchangeCU14>nlTest /DCName:Areteind.com NetGetDCName failed:
> Status = 2453 0x995 NERR_DCNotFound
```

The error says:

```
> Active Directory Domain Services was unable to establish a connection
> with the global catalog.
```

Any ideas about where I should go next?

Performed additional tests as recommended by @Greg Askew: 
 (All tests were run from Exchange Post Office - where Exchange CU14 setup initially failed from)

```
C:\Windows\system32>netdom query fsmo
Schema master               Asgard.areteind.com
Domain naming master        Asgard.areteind.com
PDC                         Asgard.areteind.com
RID pool manager            Asgard.areteind.com
Infrastructure master       Asgard.areteind.com
The command completed successfully.

C:\Windows\system32>nltest /dsgetdc:areteind.com /server:asgard
Getting DC name failed: Status = 1717 0x6b5 RPC_S_UNKNOWN_IF

C:\Windows\system32>nltest /dsgetdc:areteind.com /server:elsinore
           DC: \\Elsinore.areteind.com
      Address: \\192.168.87.3
     Dom Guid: c6193583-51f3-41b3-8681-2085733d6ea1
     Dom Name: areteind.com
  Forest Name: areteind.com
 Dc Site Name: Default-First-Site-Name
Our Site Name: Default-First-Site-Name
        Flags: GC DS LDAP KDC WRITABLE DNS_DC DNS_DOMAIN DNS_FOREST CLOSE_SITE F
ULL_SECRET WS DS_8 DS_9 0x10000
The command completed successfully
```

The last two seem to offer a hint as to why all this is happening, (but now how to fix it). The system seems to not be able to connect to Asgard as a PDC using `dsgetDC`, even though it is registered in dns by the correct ip address and definitely designated as the PDC.

To address dns, here is a screen shot of SRV records in DNS:
[image]

Comment: hey @joeqwerty, how did you change this to nonProportional font with grey background?

Comment: If you are not using IPv6 in your network, turn it off on all adapters. You will be surprised but it helps.

Comment: I disabled IPv6 on both DCs (Asgard and Elsinore), but the problem still exists.

Comment: @CharlesBretana It's [markdown formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: What do your sites look like? The initial error mentions sites. Do you have multiple AD sites? If so, do you have a DC in the same site as your Exchange box?

Comment: Can you provide output from: `NETDOM QUERY FSMO` from the Exchange server and `nltest /dsgetdc:areteind.com /server:asgard` and `nltest /dsgetdc:areteind.com /server:elsinore`.  Also update the output of ipconfig /all to show that IPV6 is disabled.

Comment: Do not disable IPv6. This is bad advice and is counter to Microsoft best practice. No problem has ever been solved by disabling IPv6.

Comment: I suspect you are correct, when I did do this, it did not fix anything, although the `ping Asgard` now shows the Ipv4 address in it's results instead of the Ipv6 address.  I will be turning it back on.

Comment: @Tim, Thanks for your time all, and yes I do not have any explicit sites. I was also curious about the mention of sites... How do I find out if my Forests, Domain is in a site ? This should be the simplest of AD domains, one forest, one tree, one site (if any) and one domain.

Comment: @CharlesBretana: As an FYI: In Windows Vista and forward, Windows prefers IPv6 before IPv4. That's why your ping results are as they are. That's the normal and expected behavior.

Comment: @joeqwerty,  Thanks - did not know that.

Comment: @Tim Haintz, I can see from the results of `nltest /dsgetdc:areteind.com /server:elsinore` that elsinore, at least, is in site `Default-First-Site-Name`, which is probably the single, default site created when you set up AD without specifying any sites. Not sure if it matters, but this AD domain was originally created some years ago on WIn 2000, or maybe even NT4, and has been migrated or `adPrep /DomainPrep`'d through each new release of WIn Server since then.

Comment: @Greg, I turned IPv6 back on and reran the three tests you suggested, they were identical

Comment: What is the status of the Netlogon service on ASGARD?

Comment: Ding!!!  Netlogon service on ASGARD was not running, and it's startup property was set to Manual... (Now why was that, I wonder)?  I started it and now `nltest /dsgetdc:areteind.com /server:asgard` now  works. I imagine I should change it's startup property to Automatic?  I will reattempt the CU14 update now. If it works, please enter an answer to this affect and I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> nltest /dsgetdc:areteind.com /server:asgard
>   Getting DC name failed: Status = 1717 0x6b5 RPC_S_UNKNOWN_IF

That can be caused by the NETLOGON service not running. The only reason I can think of that it would be stopped/set to manual is someone (perhaps temporarily) did not want the DC to serve authentication requests.

Comment: This indeed eliminated the error during CU14 setup.  Thanks!  Although I'm still confused as to why it was in Manual, this was a new Win Server 2016 install, only a few weeks ago. The default for startup setting should have been "Automatic". After which I added AD services to it. oh well....

Answer (score -1):

Is your dns properly configured? Are the srv records present and can the client machine resolve those? More information could be found [at microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961719.aspx)

Running `ifconfig /registerdns` on the domain controller can help getting those records straight.

Comment: The domain controllers are added twice (one with the first letter uppercase and other one all lower). While this should work fine it's better to use it the way god intended ;)

Comment: "the way god intended" - which is?  I take it I should eliminate the duplicates... Does it matter which one I delete?

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4343 Generally, it's not case sensitive. Just keep everything consistent for your own sanity. I personally use uppercase for all short named servers and all lower for longer named.

Comment: thanks.  I deleted all the mixed case ones, but funny, the dns seems to have recreated some of them... I'm not sure why. Oh well, it works so I won't waster time trying to figure it out.